# Python: Game menu options prompting out of order

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently creating my first "big" python project. In the game you are a wizard who has to fight a monster using abilities. If you reach 0 HP you lose. If the monster reaches 0 HP you win.

My question is:
I've created a menu which can be operated by the keys 1, 2, 3 and 4.
This is the code:

```
menu = int(input('''
             Press 1 to battle!
             Press 2 to get to the shop
             Press 3 to get to the upgrades
             Press 4 to exit the game'''))
buying = int(input('''
               (1)Buy an apple!
               (2)Buy a cake!
               (3)Buy a MedPack!'''))

if menu == 1:
   print("You can use your Abilities with A, B and C")
   print(" ")
   while health_player >= 0:
       spells = input("Press a for an attack, b for a fire ball or C for a Thunder!"
       if spells == "A":
           damage_monster = random.randrange(10, 30)
           health_monster -= damage_monster
           print("The monster lost", damage_monster, "HP and still has", health_monster, "/200 left.")
           damage = random.randrange(10, 30)
           health_player -= damage
           print("You lost", damage, "HP and still have", health_player, "/200 left.")
           print(" ")
```

... followed by other menu options:

```
elif menu == 2:
    print('''
    -----------------------
    Welcome to the shop!
    Buy an apple to get a part of your health back!
    ''')

elif menu == 3:
    pass

elif menu == 4:
    sys.exit()
```

However, the menu option selection isn't working as expected.  The shop always comes up even if I press 1, 3 or 4. How can I fix this?

Hope you can understand and help me. :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ask one question at a time see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275908/more-than-one-question-per-post)

Comment: okay well i will read the post and remove the first question. thank you and sorry for being kinda harsh. am working on this project for quite some time today and yesterday and this is the biggest problem which is kinda worrying me :/ thanks though

Comment: Can you post the exact code ? There is a missing closing parenthesis on this line `spells = input("Press a for an attack, b for a fire ball or C for a Thunder!"`

Comment: This is the code in a pastebin document https://pastebin.com/d9TH5BA9

Comment: OP update your question accordingly

Comment: what to or how do you mean that

Comment: [Here](https://pastebin.com/8YRG2ezQ) is a version of the code I have no issues with, can you confirm ?
Also, I would advise you to use a function whenever you have repeated portions of code.

Comment: I ran your code and it doenst work. I still get to the shop even though I press 1. I dont really understand your advice. Could you clarify and give an example maybe? Would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit:

Answer completely re-written in light of new information and code.

If I understand your issue correctly:
- **Why am I being prompted to buy something if I don't select '2' from the menu?**

This is because the 'buying' `input` prompt immediately follows the 'menu' `input` prompt.  As shown below.  Since this game is written in script for, the code runs top to bottom.

```
menu = int(input('''
             Press 1 to battle!
             Press 2 to get to the shop
             Press 3 to get to the upgrades
             Press 4 to exit the game'''))
buying = int(input('''
               (1)Buy an apple!
               (2)Buy a cake!
               (3)Buy a MedPack!'''))
```

I suggest you move the 'buying' prompt inside the `elif menu == 2` block.

As shown here:

```
if menu == 1:
    # Do battle stuff ...
elif menu == 2:
    print('''
    -----------------------
    Welcome to the shop!
    Buy an apple to get a part of your health back!
    ''')
    # Move your 'buying' prompt here:
    buying = int(input('''
                   (1)Buy an apple!
                   (2)Buy a cake!
                   (3)Buy a MedPack!'''))
elif menu == 3:
    # Do menu 3 stuff ...
elif menu == 4:
    sys.exit()
```

I've tested this logic and it appears to be working correctly.  Give it a go ...

#### Suggestions:

1) Have a look into [string formatting](https://pyformat.info/).  This will give you some power and control over your on-screen prompts.

2) Consider writing your game in [`functions`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp), or if you want to take it a step further, [`classes`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp), rather than as a script.  This will give you **a lot** more flexibility.  Give it a try!

Comment: Hey :) Thanks for your quick reply. I tried it and sadly it didnt work. This is the menu code menu = int(input('''
             Press 1 to battle
             Press 2 to get to the shop
             Press 3 to get to the upgrades
             Press 4 to exit the game'''))

buying = int(input('''
               (1)Buy an apple!
               (2)Buy a cake!
               (3)Buy a MedPack!'''))

Comment: @Constantin - Ok.  Will have a look a bit later tonight.  In the mean-time, would you mind updating your original question with this menu code, please?  Then I can test the full block.

Comment: This is the code in a pastebin document pastebin.com/d9TH5BA9

Comment: Wow thanks! Can’t try it out right now but I will do that as soon as possible. I was thinking about giving the player a class in which the health is given so it is general but I had a look at classes and I just couldn’t wrap my head around it. Could you maybe give an example of a class(maybe of the player class)? I think it would generalise it and make the code shorter

Comment: No worries.  The `classes` link above takes you so the w3schools site and the class example is that of a person.  So you can very easily evolve this logic into a player.  Play around with it and see how you get on.  It'll definitely add generalisation and flexibility to your code.  It's worth understanding.  (Aside, if this works for you, please make the answer as accepted.  Thanks!)

Comment: Okay that’s great! Could I use the health which is defined in the class player and put it into the fighting code? So instead of health_player (or something like this) using the class attribute?

Comment: Yes, of course!  The basic logic is to instantiate your player class with say `player1 = Player()` at a battle class level.  Then, throughout the battle you can call `player1.health - 50`, for example.  Then, at the end you can say `'Player1 has {} health remaining.'.format(player1.health)`.

Comment: I created a class and moved the buying prompt into the elif. i moved the class into the battleing code and changed the while health_player <= 0: to while Player <= 0: here is the pastebin https://pastebin.com/b3rWW9s4 . sadly i get the following error message while Player >= 0:
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'type' and 'int how can i change the type so that is accepts a class? Kind regards and thank you very much for your help!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/P4asSq5D this is the right pastbin my bad

Comment: Nice!  Just had a **very quick** scan.  Looks like you're passing a `str` value of 200 into the class and then performing mathematical operations (+= / -=) to a string.  Nope.  The health value passed into the class must be an `int` or `float` to do math against it.  Try that.

Comment: yeah i realised that. how do i change it to an int or float?

Comment: Don't overthink it ... `p1 = Player(200)`

Comment: Ah yeah. I tried it with this p1 = Player(200)
p1.playerhealth()
while Player >= 0:
    spells = input("Press a for an attack, b for a fire ball or c for a Thunder!").capitalize()
    if spells == "A":
        damage_monster = random.randrange(10, 30)
        health_monster -= damage_monster
        print("The monster lost", damage_monster, "HP and still has", health_monster, "/200 HP left.")
        damage = random.randrange(10, 30)
        Player -= damage
        print("You lost", damage, "HP and still have", Player, "/200 HP left.")
        print(" ") and it doesnt work. sorry